# how to create a type safe custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm calling a custom function `createUser` but I can pass numbers and not strings and it doesn't error. Equally, I can forget an argument and it still doesn't give me the red squiggles

```
      const [userState, createUser] = useCreateUser();
      ...
      <div
        onClick={(): void => {
          createUser({
            email: 'test796420@gmail.com',
            name: 'test1',
            password: 'topSecret!',
            username: 'testuser1',
          });
        }}
      >
        createUser
      </div>
```

the function looks like

```
import { useState } from 'react';

interface CreateUserShape {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  referrersCode: string;
  username: string;
}

const useCreateUser = (initialState = {}): any => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const createUser = async (user: CreateUserShape): Promise<void> => {
    if (user.email && user.password) {
      const method = 'POST';
      const redirect = 'follow';
      const headers = new Headers();
      const body = JSON.stringify(user);
      const url =
        'https://my-fancy-app.ondigitalocean.app/api/v1/onboarding/createUser';
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      const res = await fetch(`${url}`, {
        method,
        headers,
        redirect,
        body,
      });
      const response = await res.json();
      setState({ response });
    }
  };

  return [state, createUser];
};
export { useCreateUser };
```

How do I get the custom hook to enforce that only strings can be passed to it?

Comment: A good starting point would be: don't tell the compiler to completely ignore any information about the types you have inside useCreateUser by returning `any`.

Comment: should i set `useCreateUser` to return `CreateUserShape` ?? If I do i get the error `Type '{}[]' is missing the following properties from type 'CreateUserShape': email, name, password, referrersCode, username`

Comment: Do you think it _does_ return that object? That's not what's implemented, and it's not implied you do think that by the _usage_ of it (a `CreateUserShape` couldn't be positionally destructured to two variables) which makes that a baffling question. Maybe look at the types for React's own hooks for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useCreateuser` function is returning any which is going to allow anything to be returned. `const useCreateUser = (initialState = {}): any => {}`. Here you could just state the types that you want in your 2 returned values and you should get your desired result. So you can do something like the following:

```
type UseCreateUser = [
  state: any, // or state what type this should be
  createUser: (user: CreateUserShape) => Promise<void>
]
```

and then set that as your return type for the `useCreateUser()` like so:

```
const useCreateUser = (initialState = {}): UseCreateUser => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const createUser = async (user: CreateUserShape): Promise<void> => {
    if (user.email && user.password) {
      const method = 'POST';
      const redirect = 'follow';
      const headers = new Headers();
      const body = JSON.stringify(user);
      const url =
        'https://my-fancy-app.ondigitalocean.app/api/v1/onboarding/createUser';
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      const res = await fetch(`${url}`, {
        method,
        headers,
        redirect,
        body,
      });
      const response = await res.json();
      setState({ response });
    }
  };

  return [state, createUser];
};
```

Comment: that sure works, can you help me understand what's going on here `(user: CreateUserShape) => Promise<void>`

Comment: You are just stating the type of the `createUser()` function. So your `createUser()` function looks like `const createUser = async (user: CreateUserShape): Promise<void> => {}` so you have a funciton that takes in a user object and returns a promise. So you need to type it as such therefore the type of that function would be `(user: CreateUserShape) => Promise<void>`.